# Remove user snippets and other settings from cloud

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a file in my settings that is kept in the "cloud". There is a empty snippet file there that I can't sync.

What I would like to do is just completely erase all my vscode settings in the cloud, so I can start with a fresh workspace that I'll sync to my other devices later.

How can I remove my synced settings/keybindings/snippets/extensions from the vscode cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it. I couldn't find it anywhere so here it is for anyone interested:

[image]